# Alternate for Filebeat

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat, elk, elastic-beats

We are trying to implement ELK for my project and I'm very new to this stack.

Right now, we are facing a challenge to configure Filebeat in our servers due to old version of Linux.

Can anyone please recommend a lightweight solution for file shipper as an alternate for Filebeat?

Comment: How old is old?

Comment: OS version is Redhat 5.x

Answer (score 0):

Ok, RHEL 5.x is really old. Probably nothing based on Golang (like the Beats) will work because of [its minimum requirements](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MinimumRequirements).

Have you thought about using remote syslog for forwarding the data? Then you'll be more independent of your old operating system (though syslog might have its own issues). Filebeat has an [input for syslog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-syslog.html) that you could use.